# Pull back Sobolev function via piecewise regular polynomial map

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, sobolev-spaces, pullback

In the following $\mathbb P_p$ will denote the space of polynomials of degree $p$ with real coefficients.

Let $\hat\Omega=(0,1)^d$ be such that $\bar{\hat\Omega} =\bar{Q}\cup\bar{Q'}$, $Q$, $Q'$ open and connected and $\Omega$ be an open bounded connected set of $\mathbb R^d$.

Let $\mathbf F: \hat \Omega\to \Omega$ be a bi-Lipschitz map such that $\mathbf F_{|Q}\in \mathbb P^p(Q)$ and $\mathbf F_{|Q'}\in \mathbb P^p(Q')$. Moreover $\mathbf F\in C^{p-1}(\hat \Omega)$.

Assume now we have a Sobolev function $u\in H^k(\Omega)$, $k\ge 1$. I would like to know in which Sobolev space its pull-back is lying, namely $\hat u:=u\circ\mathbf F \in ?$

Any hints or references would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your statement is a bit confusing. Do you think of  $Q$ and $Q^{\prime}$ disjoint? If so, the statement can't be as $\hat{\Omega}$ is open and connected.  If they are not disjoint, they intersect on some open set, $U$. (I use $F_{A} = F|A$) On this domain, $F_{Q}$ and $ F_{Q^{\prime}}$ are the same polynomial. Take $F_{U}$ and extend it to $\hat{\Omega}$ via the polynomial's formula. Clearly this agrees with $F_{Q^{\prime}}$ and $F_{Q}$ on $Q^{\prime}$ and $Q$ as these are polynomials agreeing on an open set. In this case, your problem is easy to solve as $F$ is a polynomial on $\hat{\Omega}$

Comment: @Wraith1995 My problem is that $\mathbf F$ is a piecewise polynomial. It is a polynomial on $Q$ and on $Q'$, but not on their union. However I know it is of class $C^{p-1}$ on $Q\cup Q'$.